# BoundedPriorityBlockingQueue - thread safe, blocking and bounded?

Tags: java, priority-queue, blockingqueue

is there a priority-queue in Java which acts like LinkedBlockingQueue?

PriorityBlockingQueue is not blocking because it is unbounded.

Comment: your .... words dont make much sense - `PriorityBlockignQueue` will **always** block if you use the blocking functions ... if you want it to be bounded simply create your own class which `extends PriorityBlockingQueue` and `@Override` the blocking functions - check for your limit and call the `super` method, block otherwise

Comment: @specializt: Actually, that doesn't seem to make much sense. It's **unbounded**, so it doesn't block on `put(E)`. From the JavaDoc: "As the queue is unbounded, this method will never block". Furthermore, one does not simply override concurrent collections.

Comment: the problem is, that `put`is not blocking, because the queue is unbounded.  i am wondering whether there is a similar implemention in which `put` is blocking

Comment: @barracuda317: Checkout [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2341615/bounded-priorityblockingqueue) question (duplicate?).

Comment: @beatngu13 read my words again. And again. Of course the second "blocking functions" should actually be "blocking and nonblocking functions"

Answer (score 2):

If you don't need a full-blown `BlockingQueue` interface implementation then you can use `Semaphore` and something like this (in Kotlin):

```
interface BlockingBag<E: Any> {
    @Throws(InterruptedException::class)
    fun put(element: E)
    @Throws(InterruptedException::class)
    fun take(): E
}
class BlockingPriorityBag<E: Any>(val capacity: Int) : BlockingBag<E> {
    init {
        require(capacity >= 1) { "$capacity must be 1 or greater" }
    }
    private val queue = PriorityBlockingQueue<E>()
    private val semaphore = Semaphore(capacity)
    override fun take(): E {
        val item = queue.take()
        semaphore.release()
        return item
    }
    override fun put(element: E) {
        semaphore.acquire()
        queue.put(element)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try [MinMaxPriorityQueue](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/19.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/MinMaxPriorityQueue.html) from **Google Guava** and set a maximum size as next:

```
Queue<User> users = Queues.synchronizedQueue(
    MinMaxPriorityQueue.orderedBy(userComparator)
       .maximumSize(1000)
       .create()
);
```

**NB:** As a MinMaxPriorityQueue is not thread safe you need to use the decorator [Queues.synchronizedQueue(Queue)](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/19.0/api/docs/src-html/com/google/common/collect/Queues.html#line.372) allowing to make it thread safe.

As you need a `BlockingQueue` you will have to implement the decorator by yourself which is not hard to implement.

Here is how it should look like:

```
public class SynchronizedBlockingQueue implements BlockingQueue {

    private final BlockingQueue queue;

    public SynchronizedBlockingQueue(BlockingQueue queue) {
        this.queue = queue;
    }

    @Override
    public synchronized boolean add(final Object o) {
        return this.queue.add(o);
    }

    @Override
    public synchronized boolean offer(final Object o) {
        return this.offer(o);
    }
    ...
}
```

Then the code to create your `BlockingQueue` will be:

```
BlockingQueue<User> users = new SynchronizedBlockingQueue(
    MinMaxPriorityQueue.orderedBy(userComparator)
       .maximumSize(1000)
       .create()
);
```

Comment: As far as I know, this implementation is not thread-safe. There are many threads interacting with one queue on both sides (put and take). What are the difficulties I am facing, if the implementation is not thread-safe?